# Passing record query to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone please tell me how to access the array that would be in @brand_found (below).

I have tried @brand_found.id, @brand_found[:id], @brand_found_id... nothing seems to work.

```
@brand_found = Brand.where("name = ?", params[:brand])
```

I would like to pass the id found to the session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it's an Array, and an Array doesn't have any id.

You should iterate its elements

```
@brand_found.each_with_index do |element, index|
  session[:"brand_{index}"] = element.id
end
```

It will store the ids in `session[:brand_0]`, `session[:brand_1]` etc...

Otherwise, take the first element and store it's id directly, just append `.first`

Answer (score 1):

```
@brand_found = Brand.where("name = ?", params[:brand]).first
@brand_found.id #=> brand id
```

because `where` is returning an array of objects.